# Some options disappear on mobile UI

Tags: support, bug, mobile-web

On the mobile browser, I can't see the profile option on my Stack Overflow account (before it was there):

[image]

Also I can't see the search input field on my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:4575350+%5Blaravel%5D) (before it was there):

[image]

Comment: The missing profile link is a bug. Hopefully, it will be fixed within a day. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368666/334566

Comment: @PM2Ring thank you. Anyway, the **search input** field also disappeared on profile (Mobile UI)

Comment: Click the magnifying glass for the search bar, @sta .

Comment: @Larnu thanks, I didn't notice. It works.

Comment: I have this instead: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmhYE.png

Comment: @Nick mine too, if I resize the browser on desktop https://i.stack.imgur.com/rI63s.png but not in mobile device

Comment: @sta Yes, I meant, that's how it appears on my phone  :p

Comment: Can you add some platform details, like operating system, browser, and versions? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now).

Comment: @Peter problem fixed, Now I can see my profile name.  Anyway, my phone is Android and browser is Chrome